# Can embedded Tomcat serve resources without spring application processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot application with embedded Tomcat and a file directory with images. Can Tomcat serve these images without processed by Spring application?
I know I can set `spring.web.resources.static-locations` to custom resource directory, and I also permit the route for requesting resources. But every request still went through the filter in application. Is there any way to prevent these requests from entering the application, just processed by Tomcat?
Because I suppose that the requests whithout processed by application can help me decrease the load for application. Is this correct?

Comment: No that is not correct, as tomcat is part of your application it is part of the load. This would be true for a non-embedded tomcat althouhg it wouldn't reduce the overall load on the tomcat server it could reduce the load on that specific application.

Comment: I'm disapointed about that. But thank you @M.Deinum for your help.

Comment: Why are you concerned with this anyway? Is it an issue? As this feels like a premature optimization for an issue that isn't really an issue. If you want to prevent certain URLs from passing through the security filter chain, there are configuration options for that. But what you are actually trying to achieve isn't very clear.

Comment: What I want is just serve static file without web application, like Nginx or non-embedded tomcat can do. I've tried the speed on getting images between embedded tomcat and nginx. Tomcat is a little bit slower. But yes, this is a premature optimization and I just want to know is there anything I am misunderstand about embedded tomcat.